# Solving a system of 3 ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I have a system of ODEs  given as :

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
b'(s)+ a(s)\kappa(s)- c(s)\tau(s) =0 \\ 
c'(s)+b(s)\tau(s)=0 \\ 
\dfrac{ds}{ds_m}[1+a'(s) - b(s)\kappa(s)] =1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I specifically take $\dfrac{ds}{ds_m} = \dfrac{\kappa}{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$,

then is it possible to solve for $a, b$ and $ c$ in terms of $\kappa$ and $\tau$ , assuming $\kappa(s) \neq 0$ ?  I am not really clear on how  to proceed.

The above system actually corresponds to the transformation of a space curve given by :

$$ m(s_m) = \gamma(s) + a(s) T(s) +b(s)N(s) +c(s)B(s),$$

with $ T,N,B$ constituting the Frenet frame of $\gamma$ and $s$ the arc-length and $m$ and $\gamma$ have the same Frenet frames.